# How to find application running by HWND?

Tags: windows, security, windows-8.1, clipboard

I have a password keeper app which states that a certain other application is monitoring my clipboard. The password app only states the following as the application it is warning about:

```
HWND: 855900
```

How can I find which application it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WinSpy++](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17) utility (or [Microsoft's Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx) if you have Visual Studio) to enumerate all the windows with their handles.

Spy for Visual Studio 2013 can be found in the following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\spyxx.exe
```

Then, under Search/Find Window menu, you can search by handle.